# JSON encode error when trying to sign locally and send a raw transaction; bug or PEBKAC?

Tags: web3.py

i'm running into an issue when deploying a contract on Rinkeby.  when signing the transaction locally, i get this error:

```
TypeError: Could not encode to JSON: dict had unencodable value at keys: {'params': because (list had unencodable value at index: [0: because (Object of type HexBytes is not JSON serializable)])}
```

i've tracked it down to this signing call: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/middleware/signing.py#L159

the `rawTransaction` being referenced is a `HexBytes` object that is not JSON-serializable.

in my code locally, I've [patched the call](https://gist.github.com/rca/e87794a064f8c63b0f762f24c7a5e5ee) such that `rawTransaction` is a string and executing the transaction works.

i'm creating a `w3` instance like this, so that it has a POA middleware (that some other error was asking for) and a middleware that automatically signs and sends a raw transaction:

```
from web3.middleware import construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

[...]
        w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(settings.SMART_CONTRACT_PROVIDER_URL))

        w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

        w3.middleware_onion.inject(
            construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(self.account), layer=0
        )

        w3.eth.default_account = account.address
```

a simplified version of the breaking code is:

```
            eth_contract = self.w3.eth.contract(
                abi=contract.abi, bytecode=contract.bytecode
            )
            constructor = eth_contract.constructor(
                "0x9b3ff1111107E3ed9d3bd9aA7bfC0556981E64fc",
                "https://foo.com/",
                "https://test.com/",
            )
            tx_hash = constructor.transact()
```

the snippet above will raise the exception without my patch.  is there something i'm doing wrong or is this a bug in the code?

thanks!

[My patch](https://gist.github.com/rca/e87794a064f8c63b0f762f24c7a5e5ee):

```
from eth_account.datastructures import SignedTransaction
from eth_account.signers.local import LocalAccount
from web3 import Web3


sign_transaction = LocalAccount.sign_transaction


def patched_sign_transaction(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Patches the signed transaction result such that the raw transaction is a string

    When signing locally and sending up a raw transaction, this patch allows the payload
    to be JSON-encoded.  With `rawTransaction` as a `HexBytes` instance, JSON encoding fails.

    An alternative approach to this is create a custom JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to
    handle `HexBytes` instances and properly encodes them.

    This patch is good for now.
    """
    result = sign_transaction(*args, **kwargs)

    patched_signed_transaction = SignedTransaction(
        rawTransaction=result.rawTransaction.hex(),
        hash=result.hash,
        r=result.r,
        s=result.s,
        v=result.v,
    )

    return patched_signed_transaction


# patch in the above function to override its functionality
LocalAccount.sign_transaction = patched_sign_transaction
```

Comment: What blockchain are you targeting?

Comment: Hi @Ismael. This is targeting rinkeby while developing.

Comment: @berto did you solve this?

Comment: @NicSzerman apologies for not responding sooner; just seeing this.  I solved it by patching the upstream code; I'll edit my post with the patch.

Comment: It's been a while though; this may no longer be an issue with the upstream code.  But, I don't know; I haven't dealt with this code in months.